# How to copy a form element containing an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I want to copy an `<input name="name[]" >` array type element from one form to another. The problem I cannot solve is to assign the array value to the new element.

in javascript this works great:

```html
document.getElementById("newName").value = document.getElementById("name").value;
```

but this doesn't:

```html
document.getElementsByName("newName[]").value = document.getElementsByName("name[]").value;
```

The closest I could get is this:

```
 var names = document.getElementsByName('name[]');  // names is a Nodelist
 var array_name = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
       array_name.push(names[i].value);
                        }
 document.getElementById("newName").value = array_name;
```

But when I call the `document.getElementById("newName").value`
it returns a string (or a list of length 1) `["name1, name2"]`. What I want is an Array `["name1", "name2"]`

I'm searching for something like:

Input:

```
<form id="source">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" id="name" name="name[]">
</form>
```

Output:

```
<form id="destination">
<input type="hidden" id="newName" name="newName[]" value="">
</form>
```

UPDATE:
I found a workaround:
While `$(form)` only gives you access to the current form, `$('form')` will give access to all the forms. No need to copy the data from one form to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
let names = document.getElementsById('name').value;
document.getElementById("newName").value = names.split(', ');
```

This would assign an array of names to the value field.

Although I am not sure if that is even possible. I would guess that form arrays are saved as CSV lists in the background, therefore this code would be correct:

```
document.getElementById("newName").value = document.getElementsById('name').value;
```

Comment: same problem - if names contains a comma, the logic fails.

Comment: thats why you split it by comma with this part: `names.split(', ')`

Answer (score 0):

You could always convert the result into what you want - looks like it's an array with 1 big string so:

```
var result = document.getElementById("newName").value;
result = result[0].split(",");
console.log(result);
```

If you think a comma will be in the result you could use a different delimiter:

```
var names = document.getElementsByName('name[]');  // names is a Nodelist
  var array_name = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
       array_name.push(names[i].value);
       ...
  }
 array_name.join("__");
 document.getElementById("newName").value = array_name; 


var result = document.getElementById("newName").value;
result = result[0].split("__");
console.log(result)
    ...
```

Comment: If result contains a comma, then the split fails.

Comment: This is a good work around. I'm still hoping tI can find a more straightforward solution, similar to simple string values. Thanks.